# Log analytics event when verifying email in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-authentication, analytics, firebase-analytics

Not sure if this is possible but maybe someone knows how to work around this.

I have a web application and I'm using the new analytics for firebase. I want to create a funnel for the registration process.

My funnel will look something like this 
[image: Registration funnel]

Pretty simple right. The issue is that I don't have a way of tracking when the users verify it's own email. Maybe the firebase team can add a new automatic event like the ones described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to file a feature request, Stack Overflow is not the right spot. You cn [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with Firebase support.

But until such a feature is added, you'll have to implement the analytics event yourself. The most common way to do that is by sending the event from the client when you first detect that the email address is verified.

There are some subtle differences between this approach and one where the Firebase servers log it automatically, but it's as close as you can get for the moment, and relatively straightforward to implement.

Comment: Done. Request added. Thanks for your answer.